# How do I keep a prompt at the bottom of the screen in C?

Tags: terminal

**A brief disclaimer:** I have never posted on here before. I'm new to programming, but not computers.

I'm learning C and I've chosen a messaging application as my first "real" project. I'm trying to figure out how to keep a little prompt at the bottom of my terminal that will continue to ask you for a new string of text. I have heard of NCurses but I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible. Any help with this subject would be awesome! Also, I'm using <stdio.h> and stdliuser:14199420b.h for the console output and all that. Any extra libraries are mainly for sockets and other networking stuff that I'm learning.

Thanks!

Comment: Maintaining a prompt at the bottom of the screen requires a tty, so ncurses is your best bet here. Every other method will probably end up being harder than using ncurses.

Comment: Writing to the console other than using as a running log is surprisingly complex in C/C++.

Comment: VT compatible terminals always have ANSI escapes available to position the cursor [ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). Non-portable, and rudimentary, but you can do quite a bit with them. This would not be recommended for a portable app, but if you just want a quick hack for colors and cursor control, they can be fun to play with.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! @DavidC.Rankin is probably the closest to my original question however, putting the extra work into making it portable will equip me better for the future.

Comment: Please [edit] your tag. This issue is independent of the programming language, it depends on the terminal you use.

Comment: A simple ANSI escape "Esc[Line;ColumnH" will work on a huge range of terminals and emulators. I'd argue that if you encounter a terminal where that doesn't work, you're going to have bigger problems than just positioning the cursor. curses/ncurses is useful for complex terminal-management tasks but, in my view, it's over-complex if all you want to do is move the cursor around. Just my $0.02, as ever.